# Postgresql divide by zero caused by subquery

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a project with `Postgresql`. I have a query where I am calculating lifetime averages for readings of devices.

If the device is new it may not have any data and it is causing `divide by zero`.

My query is:

```
COALESCE(
    (
        SELECT
            fl1.totaliser_kl
        FROM
            water_readings fl1
        WHERE
            fl1.meter_id = :meterId
        ORDER BY
            read_local_at DESC
        LIMIT
            1
    ) / (
        SELECT
            DATE_PART(
                'day',
                (
                    SELECT
                        fl3.read_local_at
                    FROM
                        water_readings fl3
                    WHERE
                        fl3.meter_id = :meterId
                    ORDER BY
                        fl3.read_local_at DESC
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) :: TIMESTAMP - (
                    SELECT
                        fl4.read_local_at
                    FROM
                        water_readings fl4
                    WHERE
                        fl4.meter_id = :meterId
                    ORDER BY
                        fl4.read_local_at ASC
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) :: TIMESTAMP
            )
    )
) AS avg_l_day
```

II have tried `GREATEST` and `NULLIF` functions around the divider sub query but I get syntax errors when it executes.

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 13: SELECT ^
```

Any advice is appreciated

```
COALESCE(
    (
        SELECT
            fl1.totaliser_kl
        FROM
            water_readings fl1
        WHERE
            fl1.meter_id = :meterId
        ORDER BY
            read_local_at DESC
        LIMIT
            1
    ) / GREATEST(              <--- NULLIF / GREATEST 
        SELECT
            DATE_PART(
                'day',
                (
                    SELECT
                        fl3.read_local_at
                    FROM
                        water_readings fl3
                    WHERE
                        fl3.meter_id = :meterId
                    ORDER BY
                        fl3.read_local_at DESC
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) :: TIMESTAMP - (
                    SELECT
                        fl4.read_local_at
                    FROM
                        water_readings fl4
                    WHERE
                        fl4.meter_id = :meterId
                    ORDER BY
                        fl4.read_local_at ASC
                    LIMIT
                        1
                ) :: TIMESTAMP
            )
    ), 1                      <--- ELSE DIVIDE BY 1
) AS avg_l_day
```

Comment: when you say `GREATER` are you perhaps referring to the `GREATEST` function?

Comment: Hi @Avocado, yes, sorry. I fixed the post. The error is the same as `NULLIF`... `SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 13:`

Comment: You need to put parentheses () around the SELECT statement  when used as an argument in GREATEST.

Comment: Awesome @Bjarni Ragnarsson! That did it. Please post an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: Why are you using the same table and same record in 3 different (sub) queries? That doesn't sound very efficient to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put parentheses () around the SELECT statement when used as an argument in GREATEST.